# I want to retrieve value of radio button on sumbit and pass to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to select one value of radio button. On clicking sumbit button this value should be passed to Servlet from JSP page.

Can any one please provide a solution for this?  Below is the line of code. can any one tell what is wrong with this?

```html
<form action="saGui/RunGUI" method="post">
<p>
   <b style="font-size: 10pt; color: #336699; font-family: Arial Narrow;">
   <input type="radio" name="Optionlist" value="BackUp" id="bckup" onclick="this.form.submit()">
   Back up folders/Files on target servers.
   </b>
</p> 
<button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" id="sub">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: p>
         <b
          style="font-size: 10pt; color: #336699; font-family: Arial Narrow;">
          <input type="radio" name="Optionlist" value="BackUp" id="bckup" onclick="this.form.submit()">Back
          up folders/Files on target servers.</b>
        </p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                             <button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" id="sub">Submit</button>

Comment: Above is the line of code. can any one tell what is wrong with this?

Comment: Where's your <form action= ? Where's your servlet code? And, please update your question instead of posting code in comments.

Comment: <form action="saGui/RunGUI" method="post">                                                                                             action is url mapping from web.xml

Answer (score 0):

First remove `onclick="this.form.submit()"` from input tag and use proper servlet name.
You can get the value of radio button in servlet using
`String radio = request.getParameter("Optionlist")`.

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve your problem you should accept and upvote it.